# Add floating or double value dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need output like this:

```
1.1,1.2,...,1.9,1.10,1.11,1.12,1.13
```

I am using

```
Double[] arrayOfNumbers = new Double[List.size()];

...

double i = 1.00; i = i + 0.1
```

It is working fine till `1.9` after it comes to `2.0` I *can't receive* the correct data

```
1.10,1.11,1.12,1.13
```

Answer (score 0):

For

```
1.1,1.2,...,1.9,1.10,1.11,1.12,1.13
```

as far as I can see you have a *constant prefix* - `1` and increasing *suffix* `1..13`, so you can put it

```
   for (int suffix = 1; suffix <= 13; ++suffix) {
     string value = $"1.{suffix}";

     // value is "1.1" then "1.2" ... up to "1.13" 
     //TODO: put relevant code here 
   }
```

I use `string` for `value`, since in case of `double` `1.1 == 1.10`

If you want to generate *single* `string` you can put *Linq* query:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  string result = string.Join(",", Enumerable
    .Range(1, 13)
    .Select(suffix => $"1.{suffix}"));

  Console.Write(result);
```

Output:

```
  1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,1.10,1.11,1.12,1.13
```